# Objective-C: a Pointer That Points to Difference Classes at Different Time

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, pointers

I'm not really experienced with Objective-C. Here is a problem I encountered.

When I want to define a pointer for a particular instance of a class, I can

```
NSString* foo;
```

But is it possible to define pointers for instances of classes like this?

```
x* hotdog;  //"x" is the type of pointer hotdog is

hotdog = NSString;  //now points to NSString

hotdog* foo;  //an instance of NSString is created

hotdog = UIView;  //now points to UIView

hotdog* foo;  //an instance of UIView is created
```

How to define the class-pointer `hotdog`? (what should I replace `x` with?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pointer to an object of a type that's not yet known at compile-time (similar to `dynamic` in C#), use `id`:

```
id hotdog;
hotdog = [[NSString alloc] init];
hotdog = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Only do this when you really need it. If you use it everywhere, your code can easily become a mess since you'll lose track of the type of the variable.

---

At first I misunderstood your question. I'll leave my old answer here just in case future visitors need it.

The type of pointers to classes is `Class` and to get an object of that type use `+[NSObject class]`.

```
Class hotdog = [NSString class]; // now points to NSString
NSString *myString = [[hotdog alloc] init]; // create instance of NSString

hotdog = [NSArray class]; // now points to NSArray
NSArray *myArray = [[hotdog alloc] init]; // create instance of NSArray
```

Comment: You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. :)

Comment: This code is correct, but I believe that it doesn't answer the question. He is asking for the equivalent of templates in objective-c.

Comment: Thanks! Though this is not really what I'm looking for but I think this is the closest to what I want :)

Comment: @Arch what are you exactly looking for? If I read your question right, you want pointers to classes. `hotdog` is a pointer to a class in my example.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- Yeah, but it would be greater if I can find something that can replace the `x` (if it ever exists)

Comment: Oh then you can use either `NSObject` or `id`, but it's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Arch because you have one variable that holds objects of different types at a different time. This can easily become a mess. If you really need it, sure, use it, but don't use it everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

> what should I replace `x` with?

You should replace `x` with the name of the most specific common ancestor of the classes that you are planning to use with this pointer. In your example, that would be `NSObject`, because both `NSString` and `UIView` inherit it, and there are no other common ancestors. In the worst case, the common ancestor is `id`.

In general, tricks like that should be avoided in most situations, because reusing a pointer for something *really* different is bad for readability.

Comment: Thanks! I shall go for `NSObject` then :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working on an instance class the pointer to the class itself is simply `self`.
2. If you are working on a `class pointer` you could just use the `id` type since it is a generic type. Make sure then the object you are working on is of the expected type by using the `isKindOfClass` method if you want to invoke some methods of this class.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title.. I was talking about a type of pointer (if exists) that can point to different classes at different time.

Comment: Yes I just realise that :-)

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to define pointers for instances of classes like this?

I suppose you're asking for the equivalent of C++ templates.

You can't do it and you don't need it, just use the id type:

```
id foo= @"some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `NSObject*` or `id` as the pointer type.  `NSObject*` will accept any subclass of NSObject, while `id` will accept other Objective-C objects as well.

Note that, to avoid compiler warning messages, you must cast the pointer type back to the (presumably known) actual type before applying any sort of dereferencing operation (other than methods of NSObject).

You can, to be sure you have the expected type of object, use `isKindOfClass` to check the type:

```
if ([genericPointer isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSString* arrayElement = [(NSArray)genericPointer objectAtIndex:x];
}
```